Are there vinyl planks with large tolerance yet sturdy click locks?
I have TrafficMaster and the click locks get damaged easily, have limited tolerance, are fairly difficult to get to click in, and come out fairly easily even after clicked in.
Without necessarily mentioning the brands, would I expect to find any that counteract those disadvantages?  Dependable and quick installation along with resilience to issues during usage are worth finding [and possibly paying more].  I don't care otherwise about the thickness/mils.
Update  I did finally manage to get a small bathroom installed with that messy /messed up TrafficMaster.  Most of the pieces came out of the box already damaged: a box cutter came in handy to wrip out those sections of the click locks.  It is also quite a gymnastic to get the stuff to click in.  I will be looking for better click lock mechanisms. The only thing is that the color of the planks is quite nice. I hope it holds together in that bathroom.
Another update  I checked out Malibu Wide Plank (also available from HomeDepot) - and the click-lock on the samples are a dream vs the TrafficMaster.  I made a sizeable order: hopefully the real-deal works just as well

I'v done tons of LVP floor and I know what you are talking about.  I cannot remember the brands that were easier than others to instal, but I do remember that the "problem children" were at the bottom of the thickness pile.  For myself and my sanity I refuse to instal anything under 5.5mm.

After having tried out Lifeproof and Pergo it was clear that the latter is far more solid. Once the click locks are set on Pergo they are not going anywhere. No gaps at all between planks and no shifting.  Instead end click locks on Lifeproof easily move and were not suitable for any of my projects.
Note that Pergo is also nearly the most inexpensive: sometimes you get more than you pay for.
